# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list in python

Tags: python

I tried to run this code, but it showed an error:

```
def shoot(aliens):

    s=[0]*1000
    s[0]=0
    s[1]=1
    num=len(aliens)
    b=[[0 for m in range(1000)] for n in range(1000)]
    for j in xrange(2,num):
        for i in xrange(0,j):

                b[j][i]=s[i]+min(int(aliens[j]),f[j-i]) ##Error here
        s[j]=max(b)
```

and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "module1.py", line 67, in <module>
print shoot(line)
File "module1.py", line 26, in shoot
b[j][i]=s[i]+min(int(aliens[j]),f[j-i])
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

please help!

Edit: added more code. s, aliens and f are other arrays. I tried to save the result to the 2 dimentional array, but it showed that error.

Comment: what are `s`, `f` and `aliens`?

Comment: can you please explain what your trying to get at the end ?

Comment: well, this is a dynamic programming algorithm of shooting the maximum aliens coming to the base.

Answer (score 10):

```
s[j] = max(b)
```

doesn't treat `b` as a 2-d array of integers and pick the biggest one. `b` is a list of lists. `max(b)` compares the lists and returns the one that compares highest. (List comparison is done by comparing the elements [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).)

You want

```
s[j] = max(max(sublist) for sublist in b)
```

Comment: oh. it seems to be another error if it goes through that error above. thank you to pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
b=[[0 for m in range(1000)] for n in range(1000)]
    for j in xrange(2,num):
        for i in xrange(0,j):
             b[j][i] = s[j][i] + min(int(aliens[j]),f[j-i])
```

It seems to me likes is a 2D list (list of a list), and thus, you can't perform the operation.

```
s[j] + min(int(aliens[j]),f[j-i])
```

Comment: it is working, but is there any other way to do that because I do not want to change 1D array to 2D array.

Comment: `s` is not a list of lists.

Comment: @user2357112, if it is not a list of list, what is it then?

Comment: `s=[0]*1000` initializes `s` to a list of ints. The bugged `s[j]=max(b)` sets `s[2]` to a list, and then the error comes when the program tries to add `s[2]` to something.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with the following python code:

```html
retList = []
for anItem in aList:
   if anItem % 2 == 0:
       retList = retList + anItem
return retList
```

when I changed the "+" which I used for concatenation to an append statement:

```html
retList = []
for anItem in aList:
    if anItem % 2 == 0:
        retList.append(anItem) 
return retList
```

it worked fine.

Comment: Just a small caveat.. This code will only work if `anItem` is not a list type since `+` operand is more equivalent to `list.extend()` than `list.append()`. That is to say, when `anItem` is `[3]` but not `3`, the result will be different.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in a function as a conflict of a filled global vs. unused local variable: by mistake, I added something to a numerical local variable that was not known in the function, but known as a global variable of type string.

Cutting it down to a small and reproducible example:

```
def test():
    for j in range(2):
        print(j)
        print(i + 1) # error here, string type + 1!!
    return

i = ['a']
test()
```

which will output:

```
<ipython-input-281-10d295524223> in test()
      2     for j in range(2):
      3         print(j)
----> 4         print(i + 1)
      5     return
      6 

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

The global variable i is the string `'a'`. You cannot add `+ 1` to a string.

Right function would be, of course:

```
def test():
    for i in range(2):
        print(i + 1)
    return
```